# Set background programmatically by an xml file

Tags: android, drawable, setbackground

I have one `ImageButton` in my xml layout like that :

```
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/tabsButton"
    android:background="@drawable/button" android:layout_height="48dp"       
    android:layout_width="48dp"></ImageButton>
```

as you can see, I set the background of my ImageButton here :

```
   android:background="@drawable/button"
```

where button is an xml file that I placed in the drawable folder, below is the code of button.xml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/duscrollover" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

until now, every thing is ok and works fine, but now I want to set the background of my ImageButton programmatically in my on create, so I did just this :

```
View myView  = findViewById(R.id.tabsButton);
myView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button);
```

But, it don't recognize button in myView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button)
So how can get the reference to an xml file witch is placed in drawable folder ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you getting an error where it can't find the resource?  If so, try cleaning the project and rerunning.

Comment: You could also try changing the ImageButton to just a Button and it might work.  ImageButtons can be a little finnicky.

Comment: even if I used a Button, it didn't work, I tried also with View, and don't work too. I didn't get an error, but it underline button by a red line and he said that button cannot be resolved or is not a field. I mean, before running, button is not recognized , it's just like doesn't exist

Comment: Did you try cleaning the project yet?

Comment: Could there be an error in the button.xml? If there is, the project will treat it as if the resource doesn't exist. Happened to me just last night.

Comment: no, there is no error in the xml file, and it works fine when i set the background directly in the layout file.

Comment: I cleaned the project and it recognize it, thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

Did you check in the imports if it was your project R class which was imported instead of android.R ? This could happen :-)

Erwan